# Displaying the button beside the textfield in Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created a button "X" in a page. However, it is displayed below the textfield.

How do I display it next to the textfield with bootstrap?

[image]

```html
<div class="form-group row">
      <div class="field">
        <input
          type="text"
          id="{{ i }}"
          [(ngModel)]="fields[i]"
          name="name{{ i }}"
          (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
          class="form-control"
          #field="ngModel"
          required
        />
        <button
          class="remove"
          mat-mini-fab
          color="warn"
          (click)="removeField(i)"
          type="button"
        >
          X
        </button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe check the Bootstrap documentation? This has nothing to do with Angular..

Comment: As you can see in the code snipptet it is appearing after the textfield check your styling as @MikeOne said this has nothing to do with Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap class .form-control is setting the input field to width 100%. Either put this in your css:

```css
.form-control {
    width: 30%;  // or whatever width you want
    float: left;
}
```

Or remove the .form-control class from input and add form-horizontal if you don't care about the styling of the input field (or custom style it yourself):

```html
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="field form-horizontal">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="{{ i }}"
            [(ngModel)]="fields[i]"
            name="name{{ i }}"
            (ngModelChange)="onChange()"
            #field="ngModel"
            required
          />
          <button
            class="remove"
            mat-mini-fab
            color="warn"
            (click)="removeField(i)"
            type="button"
          >
            X
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
```